# JSON-LD: 'Syntax error: value, object or array expected.'

Tags: json-ld

I am getting the "value, object or array expected." syntax error when I test my JSON-LD code with Google's Structured Data Testing Tool. The error appears on line 143 of my code.

I am implementing Schema.org for a local business website with JSON-LD. I have 
tried replacing the `[` brackets with `}` brackets for the `image` object, and 
even tried removing the comma on line 143. I either get the same error, or new errors appear. I have searched other problems related to this error, but they both had different code.

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "image": [
  "http://secureservercdn.net/166.62.110.232/kkk.bd6.myftpupload.com/wp- 
   content/uploads/2019/05/360webclicks-logo2-4.fw_.png",
   ],
```

Highlighted error in the SDTT:

[image: accurate image of Schema markup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last value must not be followed by a comma.

So, this

```json
"image": [
  "image.png",
   ],
```

should be this

```json
"image": [
  "image.png"
   ],
```

If you only have one value, you could omit the array (`[`…`]`):

```json
"image": "image.png",
```